# Drawing a B/W grating

Tags: diagrams

I'm trying to create a `.tif` or `.jpg` image that will be used in full screen mode. The image should be filled with black and white thick lines. I need to set a width variable so I can create different images with different line thickness.  I can't figure out how to do it. Any ideas ?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX!  What has this to do with TeX/LaTeX?  In telling us that you should provide some sample code.

Comment: Hello :) I'm just trying to learn the language and i wanted to start with some simple example to compare with other languages and understand well how it works! I started to learn a bit but i wanted some example to compare with somethign i already done with other languages.

Comment: Which language exactly? You have an answer which uses TiKZ and LaTeX. But there are, of course, other possibilities. Note that drawing graphics is not TeX's strength i.e. this is not something at the heart of what TeX itself was/is designed to do. So you are beginning by trying to figure out how to complete a task which is somewhat alien to the system you are trying to learn. This suggests to me that you would be better advised to do a little more background reading first....

Comment: I did something very similar to this on MATLAB. Sometimes I have some tasks that consist of creating images with geometrical figures with exact size ( usually very small sizes).As on MATLAB it's not such an easy task I'm tring to find some other viable alternatives. ( MATLAB core is statistical analysis and plotting )

Comment: @cfr You think I can use it for this purpose? In some cases the thickness of some lines of the image can get to 0,15 mm

Comment: You can. It doesn't mean you should. Do you use TiKZ/LaTeX otherwise? If not, there are surely easier ways... If so, well, maybe.

Comment: Well at the moment I'm not planning to use it otherwise ( that doesn't mean I won't as it happens often that I have to make some statistical analysis and I need to create graphs). That said I can't find any easier solution to draw lines with exact measures (1 pixel - 0,18 mm ) and to loop the drawing. If you have any suggestion you're more then welcomed

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Some thing like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \x in {2,4,6,...,48}{
    \draw[line width=1mm] (\x mm,0) -- (\x mm, 2);
    }
    \begin{scope}[yshift=3cm]
    \foreach \x in {3,6,...,48}{
    \draw[line width=1.5mm] (\x mm,0) -- (\x mm, 2);
    }
    \end{scope}
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

To get it in `.jpg` format, compile this code:

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert=jpg]{standalone}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \x in {2,4,6,...,48}{
    \draw[line width=1mm] (\x mm,0) -- (\x mm, 2);
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

with `imagemagick` installed and `-shell-escape` option enabled.

To use it in full screen, compile this code

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert=jpg]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \foreach \x in {2,4,6,...,48}{
    \draw[line width=1mm] (\x mm,0) -- (\x mm, 2);
    }
  \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and put it in full screen (press ctrl+L)

Comment: That works perfectly! thank you:) is there any function to plot it full screen ( from beginning to end of the screen ) and get it on .jpg or similar file ?

Comment: I'm used to work with MATLAB and I created something similar to this but with a slight difference. Once the code was executed it would create a .tif image that was filled by those b/w lines. The first column would start at the beginning of the screen and the last column at the end of the screen.

Comment: Yes exactly this. How can I start drwaing from the beginning till the end of the screen ? Thank you for your help.

Comment: The effect of `ctrl + L` will depend on your viewer and OS, of course...

Comment: The problem in doing like this is that in Full Screen mode the width of the lines is different from actual one because it's like i'm zooming.

Comment: @cfr Certainly yes. :-)

Comment: @user2425899 You have to draw them big, for example, draw them with a height equal to your screen height and draw them many. By the way, is there any application for it in full screen?

Comment: I did managed to make them full screen with a width of 0,18mm but the output image is not as I expected. Every line looks like it has a different width because of the screen resolution ( if i zoom in i can see that all lines have same width). I have a FHD screen on a 15.6" laptop so my pixel size is 0,1797mm and I should be able to represent a 0,18mm line. Anyway yeah it should be used to create a full screen video

Comment: @user2425899 Sounds like a viewer issue or, rather a code/viewer combination issue, I guess. Lines of the same width look different for me too unless I zoom in. (Okular/TiKZ.)